# Find Value of Y given one Stationary Point and Equation with Unknown Variable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am doing a question from my Differentiation work.

**Given that y = $x^3-5x^2+kx$ has a stationary point where x = 2. Find value of y coordinate at stationary point.**

my knowledge so far for this question:
$dy/dx$ = 0 (gives stationary points)

Any help will be appreciated also any recommendations of good resources to learn math from? I am in high school

Comment: What do you get for $dy/dx$?

Comment: @Théophile  well X coordinate is already given as one stationary coordinate, and we need to find Y stationary point...that is in the question

Comment: Yes, I see that. But have you worked out $dy/dx$?

Comment: @Théophile yes I have found the derivative of the equation

Comment: The derivative is $dy/dx$. Once you have that, then you can set it equal to $0$ and use the fact that $x=2$ is a solution.

Comment: @Théophile so I set dy/dx = 0 but how would I use x =2 ? Sorry for me being naive

Comment: No problem. The idea is that $x=2$ is a solution to $dy/dx=0$, since it is given that there is a stationary point at $x=2$. This gives you enough information to find $k$.

Comment: You need to take the derivative of the function $y= x^3-5x^2+kx$, and then set the derivative equal to $0$.  The derivative will be a quardratic.

Comment: @Théophile Ok thank you I found y stationary point, I had to find dy/dx, find k (by subbing x=2 then subbing 2 into original equation with newly found val of k (8) to give my y stationary point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the value of y when x=2 (written in function of k) it has to substitute the value x=2 to the expression of $y=x^3-5x^2+kx=8-20+2k=-12+2k$. To eliminate the k parameter we need another equation: we can use the information that the first derivative has to be $0$ when x=2. So $\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2-10x+k=0$ when $x=2$ so: $-8+k=0$ $\to$ $k=8$. Now, we substitute $k$ to the previous equation for $y$: $y=-12+2\cdot 8=4$.

Comment: how would you validate the stationary points to see if they are correct? also is this to find stationary point Y?

Comment: Just write $y=x^3-5x^2+8x$. Calculate the derivative, and see that it is $0$ at $x=2$

Comment: If I well understand the question, in this case the text already give the stationary point to you, x=2. In general, if for "validate" you mean calculate the value of the function y in the stationary point, to do that it has to: put $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and solving the equation that you obtain with respect of x. Then you have one (or more, depending by the equation) solution(s) for x: this is(are) the x coordinate of the stationary point(s). Now you have only to substitute them to the y formula to find the value of y in the stationary points.